# Saving x,y coordinates in python

Tags: python, string, save

I am generating hundreds of lines (x,y coordinates) output in a for loop. What would be the easy way to save them into a txt file at the end of the process?

Thanks

Example of output:
…

100 23

112 18

133 67

221 99

232 100

…

Comment: ummm
 `some_file.write(output_data)`

Answer (score 2):

For example with regular [write](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
with open('filename', 'w') as fh:
    for x, y in coodrinates: 
        fh.write('{} {}\n'.format(x, y))
```

or with [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
with open('filename', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(coordinates, fh, indent=1)
```

or with [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
with open('filename', 'w') as fh:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(fh)
    for t in coordinates:
        spamwriter.writerow(t)
```

Comment: `.writerows` is more suited for the `csv` solution

Comment: Right. I will leave it as it is - you have it in your answer, so OP might have a better view on the issue

Comment: alrighty, +1 for suggesting `JSON` as a readable alternative (however you are using the wrong `dump`, should be `dump` not `dumps`)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `coordinates` is a sequence of `x`, `y` pairs

```
import csv

with open('out.txt', 'wb') as f:
    csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ').writerows(coordinates)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Unix environment. You could run this command:

```
python *your_code.py* | tee *output_file*
```

The output will print to console and the *output_file* as well.

Comment: He doesn't need to print it to console as well